# Overlapping despite topological editing

Tags: qgis, topology, overlapping-features

I am digitizing polygons from an ortophoto. In the snapping options, I enabled 'topological editing' and 'avoid intersection' of the polygon layer. I digitized some not-adjacent areas and then made a large polygon to fill the gaps between the layers. It worked perfectly and I do not see any overlaps, but when I use the Topology Checker it finds overlaps. I know how to clean them with GRASS, but I would rather prefere digitizing without overlapping....How does it works, or is there a bug?

I am using QGIS 2.14.1.

Comment: I just tried with a smaller snapping distance and now there is no problem. Maybe a too large snapping distance is a problem when the gaps between the polygons are smaller?